# Identify readmissions in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to write some SQL to identify patients who are readmitted to a hospital within 30 days of discharge, with a twist: any stay already marked as a readmission cannot count as an index admission.  As an example, given the following data:

```
patient_id  admit_date  discharge_date
123         01/01/2012    01/05/2012
123         01/15/2012    01/21/2012
123         02/10/2012    02/15/2012
```

The first row would not be a readmission since it is the first admit.  The second row would be a readmission (1/15/2012 - 01/05/2015 < 30) but the third row would not: the second row is a readmission, so the most recent admission index is 01/05/2012, (2/10/2012 - 01/05/2012 > 30 days apart).

My first thought was a self join such as:

```
select a1.patient_id, a1.admit_date, a1.discharge_date, max(nvl2(a2.patient_id, 1, 0)) as readmit
from admits a1 left join admits a2
    on a1.patient_id = a2.patient_id
    and a2.admit_date between a1.discharge_date+1 and a1.discharge_date+30
group by 1,2,3;
```

But this does not take into account the rule where re-admissions cannot serve as index admissions.  I'm using Netezza, in case it matters.

Comment: (1) I removed the extraneous database tags.  (2) I believe that solving this problem requires recursive CTEs, which are not supported by Netezza.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a few more rows in your table to complete it:

```
patient_id  admit_date  discharge_date
123         01/01/2012    01/05/2012
123         01/15/2012    01/21/2012
123         02/10/2012    02/15/2012
123         01/01/2016    01/05/2016
123         01/15/2016    01/21/2016
234         01/02/2012    01/02/2012
```

I suppose that by your definition, the fourth and fifth row will be a new series of events?

In that case I suggest that you break down the problem in a few steps:

1) put all the data into a new table where you add a couple of columns using windowing functions:
 A) Sequence (counting from 1 for each patient_id)
 B) days_since (null for first row, otherwise number of days since the most recent discharge
Your data now looks like this:

```
patient_id  admit_date  discharge_date Sequence days_since
123         01/01/2012    01/05/2012   1        Null
123         01/15/2012    01/21/2012   2         10
123         02/10/2012    02/15/2012   3         20
123         01/01/2016    01/05/2016   4        321
123         01/15/2016    01/21/2016   5         10
234         01/02/2012    01/02/2012   1        Null
```

2) self join that new table to itself (something like this)

```
Select 
  This.*,
  Case 
    when coalesce(this.days_since,9999)> 30 then 'admission'
    When prev.days_since<30 then 'duplicate re-admission'
    Else 're-admission
  End as Admission_indicator
From New_table This
left outer join new_table Prev 
  On (This.patient_id=prev.patient_id and this.sequence-1=Prev.sequence)
```